# How to filter user input so that each words has a prefix

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to create a search by `Hashtag`. The user can enter a words.

Now I need to validate:

- User has only 1 hashtag per word
- there is only 1 hashtag per word.
- If the word doesnt start with a hashtag then place one.
- User has not inputed more than 1 space delete the extra space
- The user didnt use other common delimeters to separe words like coma or semi-coma

I've produced the following code, but every time i start a new word it deletes the space between the two words and it become impossible to have 2 words or it just allows me to have a 2nd word but it does not add the `#` to the second word.

Could anyone help me with the logic of my validation please?

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    // Delete double spaces between words
    NSString* str = [textField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@" "];

    if ( [str isEqualToString:@""] ) {
        return YES;
    }

    // Check for other methods that people could use to separate strings
    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"#"];
    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@";" withString:@"#"];

    // separate string by Hashtag
    NSArray * words = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"];
    NSMutableArray * ma =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (NSString* str4 in words) {
        if ( ![str4 isEqualToString:@""]) {
            // Separate string by space
            NSArray * words2 = [str4 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
            if ( [words2 count] != 0) {
                [ma addObjectsFromArray:words2];
            }
        }
    }
    words = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:ma];
    NSString * newStr = [[NSString alloc]init];

    // Make the new string
    for (NSString* str2 in words) {
        if ( ![str2 isEqualToString:@""]) {
            NSString* str3 = str2;
            str3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"#%@ ",str3];
            newStr = [newStr stringByAppendingString:str3];
        }
    }
    textField.text = newStr;
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delegate method you're using is called every time the user taps a key on the keyboard, or pastes into the text field.

When is it called, the text field's `text` property is still the same as it was before the user tapped the key. The method is called to ask if the user's proposed change is allowed into the field. So, your method has a couple of problems:

- You're performing all your validation on the contents of the text field before the change has actually been made, so you'll actually be validating what was entered on the *previous* key press. You can overcome this by making the change yourself at the start of the delegate method and performing your validation on that new string:

  ```
  NSString *proposedText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:replacementString];
  ```
- You're returning `YES`, saying it's OK to make the proposed change, and also updating the text field's text value. This means the proposed change may then happen to the value that you've just updated. If you're setting the text yourself in this method, return `NO`.